# How can I reverse a stack?

Tags: vb.net, stack, reverse

I need to write a VB.NET code to reverse the given characters using a stack.
Input: 'S','T','A','C','K'

So far I have input the letters, but I don't know how to get the console to reverse it. I'm a beginner to programming so please excuse my ignorance.

An explanation as to how it's done would also be greatly appreciated.

What I got so far.

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim StackObject As New Stack
    StackObject.Push("S")
    Console.WriteLine(StackObject.Peek)
    StackObject.Push("T")
    Console.WriteLine(StackObject.Peek)
    StackObject.Push("A")
    Console.WriteLine(StackObject.Peek)
    StackObject.Push("C")
    Console.WriteLine(StackObject.Peek)
    StackObject.Push("K")
    Console.WriteLine(StackObject.Peek)
End Sub
```

End Module

I just need it to be reversed.

I got it!!

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim StackObject As New Stack
    StackObject.Push("S")
    StackObject.Push("T")
    StackObject.Push("A")
    StackObject.Push("C")
    StackObject.Push("K")

    For Each cur As String In StackObject
        Console.WriteLine(cur)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Module

That's how it's done.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, and tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: That works, though I think your tutor probably wants you to use Pop() as opposed to a foreach. If you're interested try and do it using the other method as well, it should only be a couple of lines.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli How would I use pop? I tried but it didn't work and I deleted that code to start over.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it, by the way, if your solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim StackObject As New Stack
        StackObject.Push("S")
        StackObject.Push("T")
        StackObject.Push("A")
        StackObject.Push("C")
        StackObject.Push("K")

        For Each cur As String In StackObject
            Console.WriteLine(cur)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 5):

Say you had a stack of plates:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

To reverse them, you take the first plate off, then drop it onto a new pile

```
2
3
4
5 1
```

Then you take the next plate off and drop it on the pile.

```
3
4 2
5 1
```

Repeat!

Comment: It makes sense what you're saying, but I just don't know how to make it happen.

Comment: Two stacks - yours and another one that's the "new pile".

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code (I really don't know VB.NET):

```
While (not end-of-input) Do Stack.Push(ReadNextInputChar); 

While (not Stack.IsEmpty) Do WriteCharToOutput(Stack.Pop);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the VB syntax, But this is how we can proceed to reverse a stack. This is in-place too. (it makes use of recursion)

```
void appendToStack (std::stack<int> &stk, int newElement)
{
    if (stk.empty())
        stk.push(newElement);
    else
    {
    int oldElement = stk.top();
    stk.pop();
    appendToStack (stk, newElement);
    stk.push (oldElement);
    }
}

void reverseStackInplace (std::stack<int> &stk)
{
    if (stk.empty())
        return;
    int element = stk.top();
    stk.pop();
    reverseStackInplace(stk);
    appendToStack (stk, element);
}
```